# Print method for node object not working

Tags: python, methods, linked-list, nodes

I'm teaching myself Python using `How to Think Like a Computer Scientist`. I copied this code out of the text, but mine is throwing an error for some reason. Can anyone see what I'm missing? Why does Python say that `print_list` is not defined?

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, cargo = None, next = None):
        self.cargo = cargo
        self.next = next

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.cargo)

    def print_list(node):
        while node:
            print node,
            node = node.next
        print
```

Here is the error:

```
==== RESTART: /Desktop/Programming Career/Untitled.py ====

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Users/Desktop/Programming Career/Untitled.py", line 24, in <module>
print_list(node1)
NameError: name 'print_list' is not defined
```

I tried defining print_list like this:

```
def print_list(self):
    for node in self:
        print node,
        node = node.next
    print
```

But I get the same error:
`NameError: name 'print_list' is not defined`

Comment: Move `print_list` out of the definition of `Node`.

Comment: There is problem with your code indentation , Please fix it , so we can help you!

Comment: Unindent the function `print_list()` which is not part of the class `Node`.

Comment: @ForceBru Thanks for the tip! I have fixed indentation

Comment: Is `print_list` in class scope? why it doesn't have `self` ?

Comment: @Arman Thanks for the tip! I have fixed indentation.

Comment: @Arman - That's exactly what I was wondering. I'm following along in the text and until now, we used self. Without explanation they used node this time. I'm trying to try it with self now.

Comment: `def print_list(self):`
        `for node in self:`
            `print node,`
            `node = node.next`
        `print`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined a method `print_list()` but you're trying to call it as a function. Remove the indentation before `def print_list(node):` and it will then be a function.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, cargo = None, next = None):
        self.cargo = cargo
        self.next = next

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.cargo)

def print_list(node):
    while node:
        print node,
        node = node.next
    print
```

Or make it a method and then call it as such:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, cargo = None, next = None):
        self.cargo = cargo
        self.next = next

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.cargo)

    def print_list(self):
        node = self
        while node:
            print node,
            node = node.next
        print
```

then instead of `print_list(node1)` you can call `node1.print_list()`

Note that if you do make it a method it would have worked as you had written it but it seems cleaner to use the convention `self` for the first argument and while you can rebind `self` it is probably clearer not to.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you wanted the function `print_list` to not belong to the Node class. If this is the case just remove the indentation for the print_list function. 
Python doesn't use brackets like java or C++ but uses indentation instead. In this case Python interprets `print_list` as a function belonging to the Node class.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, cargo = None, next = None):
        self.cargo = cargo
        self.next = next

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.cargo)

def print_list(node):
    while node:
        print node
        node = node.next
print
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was trying to do. I'm mixing up methods and functions. Thank you so much!